# How to manually cluster nodes on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two servers.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

In elastic search config, how to I manually add.  I am not a fan of discovery.  It does not work.

Each node is eligible to be master.  I am using digital ocean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using zen discovery, you can disable the multi-cast option and set the addresses of the unicast hosts to discover.

If you're using the default port of 9300 on your nodes, the settings below should work in your configuration file

```
# disable multicast
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

# set the list of hosts for unicast discovery
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [“xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx”, “yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy”]
```